# WPF binding from two sources

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm trying to display some albums in controls with size determined in runtime

XAML:

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AlbumsTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Border Width="{Binding ThumbWidth}" Height="{Binding ThumbHeight}">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Cover}"/>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Albums}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource AlbumsTemplate}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
```

ViewModel.cs

```
    class ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public int ThumbWidth { get; set; }
    public int ThumbHeight { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ThumbWidth = 150;
        ThumbHeight = 150;
        Albums = DataSupplier.Instance.GetAlbums();
    }
}
```

Album Class

```
    class Album
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Cover { get; set; }

    public Album(string name, string artist, BitmapImage cover)
    {
        Name = name;
        Artist = artist;
        Cover = cover;
    }
}
```

I can see all albums with name, artist, and cover, but the cover has no the correct size.

In controls outside the DataTemplate I can retrieve ThumbWidth and ThumbHeight

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that your current DataContext is `Album` and not `ViewModel`. You can only have **one** DataContext.

1. A fast way to solve this problem would be to add `ThumbWidth` and `ThumbHeight` to your `Album`-class.
2. I **would prefer** to add a class `AlbumViewModel` which contains all kind of information, which is need for showing the album (like: witdh, height, name, title, ...). In addition a list of `AlbumViewModel`s is located in your `ViewModel`. Doing it like this is common used solution for your problem in MVVM.
3. Another *hacky* way is, to access the parent's data context properties in your xaml:

   `{Binding ThumbWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}`

   more about doing this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037096/wp8-access-datacontext-of-parent).

Comment: I tried, with success, adding the size parameters to the Album class, I just thought that I could accomplish the task with less redundant data... so I applied successfully your third advice!

I'm going to try your prefer method

Thank you David!

Answer (score 0):

Without having to add the height/width to each `Album`, you can use the `DataContext` of the `ListBox` (which is where the height/width) currently is.

You can do this by using a `FindAncestor` binding

```
   <Border Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext.ThumbWidth}" 
           Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext.ThumbHeight}">
```